# bullet points not remaining central when resizing fluid container

Tags: html, css

I've just registered here and I am looking for a little help.

I'm working on my tribute page for free code camp and the bullet points I have are not remaining central when resizing the fluid container.

Does anyone have any ideas?
[image]

Here is a link to my code pen so you can take a look [code pen](http://codepen.io/Rob100/pen/grzPAd?editors=1100)

```css
body {
  margin: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
  font-size: 100%;
}

h1 { 
  font-family: lobster, Monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em; /* 80px/16=5em */
  text-decoration: underline; 
  margin-bottom: 60px;  
  border-style: ;
}

blockquote {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Puritan', cursive;
  color: black;
}

.img-r { 
  /* other definitions */
  width:100%;
}

.padding {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

li { 
  font-family: Monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em; /* 80px/16=5em */
  text-decoration: ; 
  margin-bottom: 60px;  
  border-style: ;
}

@media  (max-width: 700px){
  .jumbotron p {
    font-size: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<h1> 
Dame Stephanie "Steve" Shirley
</h1>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-6">
                        <h2 style="color: #645340; text-decoration: underline;" class="text-center">About
          Dame Stephanie "Steve" Shirley </h2>
                        <ul class="text-center">
                            <li class="text-center"><em>Dame Stephanie "Steve" Shirley was born as Vera Buchthal to a Jewish father, a judge in Dortmund who lost his post to the Nazi regime, and a non-Jewish Viennese mother.</em>
                            </li>
                            <li class="text-center"><em>In July 1939, at the age of five, Shirley arrived, together with her nine-year-old sister Renate, to Britain as a Kindertransport child refugee.She was placed in the care of foster parents living in the Midlands town of Sutton Coldfield.</em>
                            </li>
                            <li class="text-center"><em>After leaving school Vera decided not to go to university (botany was the "only science then available to my gender") but sought employment in a mathematics/technical environment. At the age of 18, she became a British citizen and changed her name to Stephanie Brook.</em>
                            </li>
                            <li class="text-center"><em>After leaving school Vera decided not to go to university (botany was the "only science then available to my gender") but sought employment in a mathematics/technical environment. At the age of 18, she became a British citizen and changed her name to Stephanie Brook.</em>
                            </li>
                            <li class="text-center"><em>In the 1950s, Stephanie worked at the Post Office Research Station at Dollis Hill, building computers from scratch and writing code in machine language. She took evening classes for six years to obtain an honours degree in mathematics. In 1959, she moved to CDL Ltd, designers of the ICT 1301 computer.</em>
                            </li>
                            <li class="text-center"><em>After marriage to a physicist, Derek Shirley, in 1962, Shirley founded, with a capital of £6, the software company Freelance Programmers</em>
                            </li>
                            <li class="text-center"><em> She wanted to create job opportunities for women with dependents, and predominantly employed women, with only 3 male programmers in the first 300 staff,[8] until the Sex Discrimination Act 1975 made that practice illegal.</em>
                            </li>
                            <li class="text-center"><em>She adopted the name, Steve, to help her in the male-dominated business world.[9] Her team's projects included programming Concorde's black box flight recorder.</em>
                            </li>
                            <li class="text-center"><em>Shirley retired in 1993 at the age of 60 and has since focused on her philanthropy.</em>
                            </li>
                            <li class="text-center"><em>Shirley was appointed Officer of the Order of the British Empire (OBE) in the 1980 Queen's Birthday Honours, for services to industry and promoted Dame Commander (DBE) in the New Year Honours, 2000 for services to Information Technology.</em>
                            </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-r center-block" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/480xn/p014nf75.jpg">
                            <div>
                                <p class="text-center padding">
                                    Dame Stephanie "Steve" Shirley
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Much appreciated,

R

Comment: Can you expand upon the issue? In your CodePen example, the bullet points seem to stay centered in their column when the screen is decreased to a mobile size. The do look off-center somewhat because the  column on the right is taking up some room, as it should. Do you want to change to a full width column on mobile?

Comment: They are working just fine. You probably dont want them on the left side am I right? Using list with such styling and center text alignment is a bit ugly.

Comment: But I agree with @Josh that the question has wrong title. The bullets are always aligned to the left. Or you see it something else?

Comment: @Josh When window is resized the bullet point list is centred in the left column but not aligned with the title centred immediately above in the same column. No I don't want to change to a full width column on mobile.
Thanks for your replies

Comment: I know the styling isn't good right now but want to know why it doesn't display correctly.

Comment: The list is not aligned with the title because the list has a left-padding, as it should, so that the bullets are visible and there's spacing between them and the text. You could either remove the 40 pixels of left padding on the ul.text-center element or add 40 pixels of left-padding to the title.

Comment: @Josh Cool, I did that and it worked. How did you know the list has 40px left padding by default?
Thanks

Comment: I knew that the list had 40px of padding by looking at it with Google Chrome dev tools (inspector) and looking at the "Computed" tab, which shows you the elements dimensions and margins/padding.

Comment: @Josh Thanks for the info! Your answer was posted as a comment, so I cannot mark my question as answered. Should I answer it and say where I got the info in this situation or do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list is not aligned with the title because the list has a left-padding, as it should, so that the bullets are visible and there's spacing between them and the text. You could either remove the 40 pixels of left padding on the ul.text-center element or add 40 pixels of left-padding to the title.